# Create a formula for velocity based on rotation in 2d?

Tags: math, 3d, rotation, velocity

So I have a bit of a math problem.  Here are the pieces.

```
Input:
Rot = Rotation (degrees).  This is the rotation of the "player".  This is also the yaw.
Vel.X = This is the left/rightward movement that would be happening if it weren't rotated
Vel.Z = Same as last except its up/down movement

Output:
Result.X = This is the actual movement that should be happening along the x axis considering rotation
Result.Z = Same as last
```

Basically the scenario is that a player is standing on a platform with "Rot" rotation.  When directional keys are pressed velocity is added accordingly to the "Vel" value.  However if rotation isn't 0 this wont produce the right result because when the player rotates moving left becomes relative.

Could you please tell me a formula that would find the proper x and y movement that would result in the player moving around relative to its rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is probably the most basic rotation question in game programming.

Using your `Vel.X` and `Vel.Z` values, you have what you might think of as the vector you wish to rotate in the x/z plane (instead of x/y - but same idea).  Whether velocity or position, the approach is the same.  With a simple google search we find that for 2D vector rotation, the formula is:

```
Result.X = Vel.X * cos(Rot) - Vel.Z * sin(Rot);
Result.Z = Vel.X * sin(Rot) + Vel.Z * cos(Rot);
```

Comment: Note that you may need to add/subtract Pi/2 (or Pi, etc) from `Rot` depending on what you mean by `0`.  And most programming trigonometry is done in *radians*, not degrees.

Comment: Thankyou much! Turns out all i was missing was the "-" instead of "+"